# Does Dany get Infected?

Tags: plot-explanation, game-of-thrones

In episode S5E09 of Game of Thrones we saw Jorah give a hand to help Dany from the Sons of the Harpy, given the fact that [Greyscale infection](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Greyscale) spreads by touch, does this mean Dany is infected?

Comment: It seemed to me that it is only a problem when you touch those parts that are actually infected (which for him is only a small spot on the arm for now). He wouldn't have reached out for her otherwise.

Comment: @NapoleonWilson 's input was my general assumption after watching the episode, but having an exact answer would definitely be worthwhile as I was wondering this myself. Given Jorah knew to tell Tyrion not to touch them when they had their encounter, I'd say he's familiar enough with how the disease is transferred. I'd say it lends credence to the assumption as well, given the Stone Men are fully infected, so touching any part of them should be avoided.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A quick google image search shows that Jorah's grayscale is on his left forearm:

[image]

He takes Dany's hand with his right hand, while both his forearms are covered by leather bracers:

[image]

I guess it's possible that whatever drives the disease could exist elsewhere on the skin without being visible, or might be like systemic viruses that cause rashes to develop in random places - but I don't see any reason to believe that.

Neither Jorah nor Shireen developed theirs anywhere but where the source touched, and it spreads slowly from where it starts rather than appearing in blotches - suggesting it needs **direct contact** to spread.

So Dany's safe - unless Jorah scratched and forgot to wash his hands...