# Are Stone Men suffering from greyscale?

Tags: game-of-thrones

During season 5 of *Game of Thrones* we see that some Stone Men attack Jorah Mormont and Tyrion and now Jorah is also converting into Stone Man. His skin is becoming black and hard.

At the same time Shireen, daughter of Stannis Baratheon, has black skin on her 
face due to greyscale. Are both the same disease?

Does greyscale spread through touch? And how much time does it take to spread in the body? Cause Shireen had it for long time, still not transformed her completely, which means Jorah has lot of time.

Or am I confusing two different things to be the same?

Comment: Are they suffering from greyscale?  No, the entire series is filmed in color.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You're not confusing anything, it is the same disease.

However [Shireen](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Shireen_Baratheon) has only a relatively small scar not because it's an early stage, but because she is cured - see below.

[Greyscale](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Greyscale) spreads through touch:

> Greyscale is extremely infectious, spread through touch contact with
>   an infected person, or even spread on unsterilized objects that have
>   been touched by the infected.

People infected with greyscale eventually become [Stone Men](http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Stone_Men), unless they die earlier. It is also possible to recover, which is rare, but happens.

> Those that manage to survive a bout with the illness will be immune
>   from ever contracting it again, but the flesh damaged by the ravages
>   of the disease will never heal, and they will be scarred for life.

This was the case with Shireen.

It takes a long time for an infected person to reach the "Stone Man stage":

> Greyscale kills slowly, often taking many years to progress to a
>   terminal state. Long before that, in the mid-to-late stages of the
>   disease, the infection will spread to cover all of the victim's skin
>   from head to toe, leaving them in agony. An infected person can
>   survive like this for years, living in misery as one of the Stone Men.
>   In the very final stages of the disease, (perhaps years after the skin
>   is completely covered with it), it starts attacking the body's
>   internal organs, hardening them as it did the outer flesh. When it
>   spreads to the brain, the deterioration can result in violent
>   insanity.

Comment: Does it mean that Daenerys could be infected, too? She touched Jorah's hand in the arena after Sons of Harpy attacked...

Comment: @vojta Check this question: http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/35194/does-dany-get-infected

Answer (score 8):

Are both the same thing?

**Yes** both are suffering from same disease Greyscale
Per GOT WIKI:

> Jorah and Tyrion continue but Jorah looks at his wrists, and notices he has been infected with Greyscale.
>
> When Shireen was an infant, she suffered from greyscale. The disease almost killed her, and left her disfigured

Why Shireen had it for long time?

Because it was cured when she was younger.

in Season 5 discussion between Shireen and Stannis during the stay at castle black :

> **Stannis**: I was told you would die, or worse, the Greyscale would go slow and you'd grow just enough to know the world before taking it away from you. Everyone advised me to send you to the ruins of Valyria to live out your short life with the stone men before the sickness spread through the castle. I told them all to go to hell.
>
> I called in every maester on this side of the world. Every healer, every apothecary. They stopped the disease and saved your life. Because you did not belong across the world with the bloody stonemen. You were the Princess Shireen of House Baratheon. And you are my daughter.

how much time does it take to spread in the body?

Hegemon's asnswer covers that.